# SageMaker inference endpoint with HuggingFaceModel ignores custom inference.py script

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, huggingface, inference, large-language-model, llama

I'm trying do deploy a [HuggingFaceModel](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/huggingface/sagemaker.huggingface.html#hugging-face-model) using sagemaker inference endpoint. I've been following some guides, e.g.: [this one](https://medium.com/innovation-res/inference-your-own-nlp-trained-model-on-aws-sagemaker-with-pytorchmodel-or-huggingefacemodel-30bcbdc4348b) and [this](https://www.philschmid.de/sagemaker-llama-llm). My model of choice is Llama-2 fine-tuned on my own data.
I've packed it and created a model.tar.gz which contains the following structure:

```
model.tar.gz/
├── config.json
├── generation_config.json
├── tokenizer.json
├── pytorch_model-00001-of-00003.bin
├── ... (other model files)
└── code/
  ├── inference.py
  └── requirements.txt
```

My `inference.py` script defines the functions  `model_fn` and `output_fn`, with custom model loading and output parsing logic.

I've uploaded this model.tar.gz to the S3 bucket in `model_s3_path`.

During the sagemaker endpoint creation, I define my HuggingFaceModel as follows:

```
from sagemaker.huggingface import get_huggingface_llm_image_uri
from sagemaker.huggingface import HuggingFaceModel

llm_image = get_huggingface_llm_image_uri(
  "huggingface",
  version="0.9.3"
)

huggingface_model = HuggingFaceModel(
    model_data=model_s3_path,
    role=aws_role, 
    image_uri=llm_image,
    env={
      'HF_MODEL_ID': 'meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-hf',
      'SM_NUM_GPUS': '1',
      'MAX_INPUT_LENGTH': '2048',
      'MAX_TOTAL_TOKENS': '4096',
      'MAX_BATCH_TOTAL_TOKENS': '8192', 
      'HUGGING_FACE_HUB_TOKEN': "<my-hf-token>"
    }
)
```

And then I deploy the model:

```
huggingface_model.deploy(
    initial_instance_count=1,
    instance_type=inference_instance_type,
    endpoint_name=endpoint_name,
    container_startup_health_check_timeout=300
)
```

However, during the inference, the resulting endpoint model doesn't seem to use any of the functionality from `inference.py`, but rather sticks to all default methods. For instance, it still returns response as `[{"generated_texts": model_response}]` although my post-processing function (`output_fn`) should've changed the return type.

1. I've tried setting `entry_point="inference.py"` and `source_dir="./code"` during the HF model creation - the endpoint was not deploying at all.
2. Used env variable `"SAGEMAKER_PROGRAM": "inference.py"` - did not change the model's responses, functionality from `inference.py` still was ignored.
3. Tried various `image_uri` - did not change the endpoint's behaviour.

Comment: I believe TGI doesn't support custom inference.py script. One way to deal with this is to use SageMaker LMI container which will support your own model script. Please refer the example here - https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-generativeai/blob/main/instruction-fine-tuning/gpt-neo/djl_deploy_GPT_Neo.ipynb

Comment: Endpoint creation needs a container image and model data. Does the usage of `HF_MODEL_ID` in `env` maybe negate `model_data` as it defines model data twice?

Comment: Any solution for this.  I am also facing same issue. For HF_MODEL_ID, I have given /opt/model/ml,  still didn't help